# Unit testing a mutex lock

Tags: unit-testing, mutex

Our business has recently moved to a TDD style and I'm new at writing unit tests. The C# (.net 3.5) piece I'm writing now should be able to verify a separate process is running, as I understand it the best way using the Mutex class.

So I have a method in my SrsUpdaterController class like so...

```
public bool IsUpdaterRunning()
{
    Mutex srsUpdaterMutex = new Mutex(false, SRS_UPDATERGUID);
    if (srsUpdaterMutex.WaitOne(0)) //If SRS Updater is running
    {
        srsUpdaterMutex.ReleaseMutex();
        srsUpdaterMutex.Close();
        return false;
    }
    else                            
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and I have a test

```
[TestMethod()]
public void IsUpdaterRunningTrueTest()
{
    SrsUpdaterController target = new SrsUpdaterController();
    string mutexGuid = SrsUpdaterController.SRS_UPDATERGUID;            
    bool expected = true;
    bool actual;

    Mutex srsUpdaterMutex = new Mutex(false, mutexGuid);            
    srsUpdaterMutex.WaitOne(3000);
    actual = target.IsUpdaterRunning();           
    srsUpdaterMutex.ReleaseMutex();
    srsUpdaterMutex.Close();
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);            
}
```

It doesn't work because the unit test and the IsUpdaterRunning method are called by the same thread, and so [Windows is "smart" enough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to not make the process block its self. The problem is I WANT the process to block its self so that it simulates the mutex being claimed. Is there any way to do this? Or am I approaching unit testing/process synchronization/mutex management all wrong?

(note, I did also try locking the Mutex on a separate thread launched from the test, but it still allowed me to claim the mutex in both places. Which is ok because I'd rather avoid threads when possible)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is perhaps a scenario that is best left not unit tested. One of the attributes of well-executed unit testing is that it should be low-effort. In theory you could break down this bit of code into layers/interfaces that could be mocked, but maybe it's more feasible to integration-test this bit manually. Pick your battles wisely.